# Is there any way to tell where a page element is loaded from in Magento?

Tags: template, blocks

When I see a page that uses Magento, is there any way for me to know where the elements on the page loaded from? How can I know if something is loaded from a static block or from a file somewhere? And if I know what kind of thing loaded an element can I find the file path tracing back to that element?

Comment: Take a look @ http://codegento.com/2011/03/debugging-magento-step-by-step/

Comment: The question sounds as if you mean looking on a foreign page, not your own where you could simply change the configuration (as the answers suggest)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System > Configuration > Developer (under Advanced) > Debug (then change store scope to Website View in top left) > Template Path Hints (change to Yes), and then refresh front end page.

Comment: I recommend you to use free extension called 'Easy Template Path Hints' with which you can just turn on the template path hints both for frontend and backend easily using query strings. Take a look: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html

Answer (score 0):

I am also supporting the solution told by michael.b. But if you want to identify whether it is coming from custom block or page, just turn on the 'Add Block Names to Hints' from the developer menu in configuration under template path hints. This will show you the block used by the templates and you will get a clear idea of how the html elements are loaded.